# How to get exchange rate json information using by application.properties with REST service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services

**I want to take the json data in the 'https://dovizkurlari-l6vtviaacq-uc.a.run.app/api/doviz/usd' and present it with a service. but I got an error I can't solve.**

I added the below property in my application.properties

*application.properties*

```
tcmb.request.dolar=https://dovizkurlari-l6vtviaacq-uc.a.run.app/api/doviz/usd
```

Then I assign this link to the variable dolarUrl in tcmbCommon class.

*tcmbCommon.java*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TcmbCommon {

    @Value("${tcmb.request.dolar}")
    public String dolarUrl;

    }
```

and in a service class, I got the values for this service with restTemplate

*DollarService.java*

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DolarService {

    @Autowired
    TcmbCommon tcmbCommon;

    public String getDolar(){

        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        String data = rest.getForObject(tcmbCommon.getDolarUrl(), String.class);

        return data;
    }
}
```

finally I created an response service by calling the DolarService class in the DolarController class

*DolarController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/dolar")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class DolarController {

    private @NonNull
    final DolarService dolarService;

    @GetMapping("/getDolar")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sDolar(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dolarService.getDolar(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I get this error when starting the project.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tcmb.webservices.tcmbwebservices.controller.DolarController required a bean of type 'com.tcmb.webservices.tcmbwebservices.services.DolarService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tcmb.webservices.tcmbwebservices.services.DolarService' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63388', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed to write @Autowired in controller class.

```
**@Autowired
final DolarService dolarService;**
```

then try to run.

Comment: I fixed  "private @NonNull final DolarService dolarService" to "@Autowired
final DolarService dolarService;" in controller class. And also remove "@Autowired" line in DolarService, it started. But tcmbCommon is comming null.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify DolarController.java with below code while injecting dependencies to DollarService bean. I guess having `@Autowired` and final on a field are contradictory.

```
@Autowired       // this will inject the dependency of DollarService class (autowiring)
private DolarService dolarService;
```

If you want to use the final keyword autowired, you need to do constructor injection as mentioned below.

```
@Autowired
public DolarController(DolarService dolarService) {
    this.dolarService = dolarService;
}
```

Please let me know if it is still not resolved.

Comment: SOLVED. added "@Autowired DolarService dolarService;"  in dolarController, and "private @NonNull TcmbCommon tcmbCommon;" in service class. BUT it wasn't enough. Also added "@Component" annotation in common, controller and service classes. Thank you.